# Application.MessageBox cutting the message when VCL theme is applied

Tags: delphi, styles, messagebox, vcl

Version: Delphi Berlin 10.1

I am encountering problems, in what I consider to be a vcl theme bug, that when applying a vcl style theme to the application, messages using TApplication.MessageBox are limited to 256 characters.

TApplication.MessageBox with 298 characters of text WITHOUT the VCL theme applied. All text is displayed correctly.
[Link: without VCL Style Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mmKw.png)

TApplication.MessageBox with 298 characters text WITH the VCL theme applied. The text is limited to 256 characters and the rest is cut.
[Link: with any VCL Style Theme (Windows10 example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYddR.png)

I have already analyzed the TCustomStyle class of Vcl.Styles.pas but I have not found how to solve this unpleasant situation, so I would like your help.

**EDIT:**

Following the information that **Andreas Rejbrand** passed, it was possible to identify that it was a limitation in the buffer size of the GetText of TStyleHook that was limited to the array of [0..256] of char.
With this information I created a detour for a new method where I increased the buffer size to array of [0..1023] of char which solved my problem.

Bug reported in QC Embarcadero:

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14771

and

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14772

**Note:** Unfortunately updating the IDE (which would solve the problem) to a newer version is not possible at this time.

Comment: Unable to reproduce in 10.3 and Windows 7. You should give a minimal complete example demonstrating the issue. But in any case, the best solution is to NOT use VCL styles. Then you get a completely bug-free GUI that behaves exactly as people expect, and, as a bonus, you get a visually much nicer GUI.

Comment: This is a known bug. See [RSP-14772](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14772). It was fixed in Delphi 10.2.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: The comment with the bug report link and fix info should be posted as an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug.

It was reported to Embarcadero in issue [RSP-14772](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14772) and the bug was fixed in Delphi 10.2.

The best solution is to upgrade to the newest Delphi version, which also fixes a lot of other bugs.